# boost asio async_write with shared buffer over multi-thread

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Now I have a `Connection` class as shown below (irrelevant things are omitted):

```
class Connection : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Connection> {
public:
    virtual void write() {
        socket_->async_write_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer_.data(),
                                                      buffer_.size()),
                                  std::bind(&Connection::on_written,
                                            shared_from_this(),
                                            std::placeholders::_1,
                                            std::placeholders::_2));
    }

    void on_written(const boost::system::error_code& e, std::size_t length) {
        if(e) {
            // handle error here
            return;
        }

        buffer_.consume(length);
    }

    void add_to_buf(const std::string& data) {
        // add the string data to buffer_ here
    }

private:
    boost::asio::io_service& service_;
    std::unique_ptr<socket> socket_;

    boost::asio::streambuf buffer_;
};
```

As you see, the `write()` operation will write data in `buffer_` and the `buffer_` is only cleaned in the write operation completion handler. However, the problem comes, now I have the following invocation code (Note: it is multi-threaded):

```
Connection conn;
// initialization code here
conn.add_to_buf("first ");
conn.write();
conn.add_to_buf("second");
conn.write();
```

The output I want is `first second`, but, sometimes the output could be `first first second`. It happens when the second operation starts but the first completion handler has not been called. I have read about `strand` to serialize things, however, it can only serialize tasks, it cannot serialize a completion handler and a task.

Someone may suggest to call the second write operation in the first's completion handler, but, per the design, this cannot be achieved.

So, any suggestions? maybe a lock on `buffer_`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locking the buffer per se wont change anything. If you call write before the first write has completed it will send the same data again. In my opinion the best way is to drop the `add_to_buf` method and just stick to a `write` function that does both, add data to the buffer and if neccessary triggers a send.

```
class Connection : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Connection> {
public:
    virtual void write(const std::string& data) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(lock_);
        bool triggerSend = buffer_.size() == 0;
        // add data to buffer
        if (triggerSend) {
            do_send_chunk();
        }
    }

    void on_written(const boost::system::error_code& e, std::size_t length) {
        if (e) {
            // handle error here
            return;
        }

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(lock_);
        buffer_.consume(length);
        if (buffer_.size() > 0) {
            do_send_chunk();
        }
    }

private:
    void do_send_chunk() {
        socket_->async_write_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer_.data(),
            buffer_.size()),
            std::bind(&Connection::on_written,
            shared_from_this(),
            std::placeholders::_1,
            std::placeholders::_2));
    }

    boost::asio::io_service& service_;
    std::unique_ptr<socket> socket_;

    boost::asio::streambuf buffer_;
    std::mutex lock_;
};
```

The idea is, that the write function checks if there is still data left in the buffer. In this case it does not have to trigger a `do_send_chunk` call as sooner or later `on_written` will be called which then will cause another `do_send_chunk` as the new data will stay in the buffer and the `if(buffer_.size() > 0)` will be true inside `on_written`. If however there is no data left it has to trigger a send operation.

Comment: I don't follow this. Why do you trigger a send iff the buffer is empty? How does this prevent resending things, as `do_send_async` is still async and doesn't necessarily complete under the lock? (Why is `data` not being used in `write()`?)

Comment: @sehe empty buffer indicates that currently there is no other write operations, so we can setup a write operation; `do_send_async` is still under the lock, so `buffer_.data()` and `buffer_.size()` in it are protected. In `on_written()`, we check if there is additional data added by others, if there is, we write it instead of them.

Comment: @Muepe Great solution, thanks, I just did not realize that I can setup  another write operation in the completion handler.

Comment: @KelvinHu oh. My surprise was that I always thought all `asio::buffer()` wraps were zero-copy (i.e. by reference) which would make this unsafe. Also, I don't read comments: `// add data to buffer` has no side-effects :)

Comment: @Muepe Sorry, I have an additional question: if thread A is in `write()` and locked `buffer_`, at this moment thread B is doing the real write operation(means it needs to read data range specified in `do_send_async`), what will it happen? Will it affect the performance?

Comment: @sehe Yeah, I think `asio::buffer()` does zero-copy too, but as the lock guarantees there will be only one write operation at the same time, so it is safe(others will only append data at the end of buffer).

Comment: @KelvinHu The lock guarantees, that only one thread at a time can manipulate the buffer. So if thread A is in write and thread B calls write as well it has to wait until A is finished.

Comment: @KelvinHu ah, that's subtle. So, actually the buffer is unprotected during send, **but** you have an invariant that only data is ever going to be added. This will still break if the `streambuf` reallocates the underlying storage on resize. Is this guaranteed not to happen? (+1-ed because I assume you know this to be the case)

Comment: @sehe Sorry, I haven't considered this problem, I checked the code of `boost::asio::buffer()`, it just stores the raw pointer to data and size, so, if write operation happens after new data appended and reallocated... Yeah, you are right, this solution still has problem.

Comment: @KelvinHu I'm not an ASIO wiz, but I suppose that the `ConstBufferSequence` concept could be used to mitigate this issue (at the cost of fragmenting the buffer space?)

Comment: @sehe I am thinking using a `queue` to store those buffers, every time in `write()` operation we setup a new buffer and push it into queue, then it will not have the issue you mentioned.